# Sum total of two queries - Kibana Lucene syntax

Tags: lucene, kibana

I have the following queries I am running to get counts from multiple log files with custom tags. The issue is I am not able to get the sum total of 2 queries combined.

```
Query 1: tags:ppr AND tags:api AND loglevel:ERROR
Result: 203445

Query 2: tags:ppr AND tags:api NOT response:200&302
Result: 234456677
```

Issue is I want the result to be the sum of both queries but i have tried **(query1) OR (Query2)** and different combinations but the results is either query1 or query 2 and not sum of both.

Comment: Dunno why you got a downvote. It's a legit good question.

Comment: @L0j1k, this is one of the reasons why I find it difficult asking questions here. Its discouraging when someone down-votes legitimate questions. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, try simply creating subqueries by parenthesizing each query and separating them with `AND`, like `(query1) AND (query2)`. If this does not give you the result you want, you can try another solution which gets you the desired end result (though maybe not exactly how you'd imagined)...

With these two queries enabled, create a  new (or modify an existing) 'histogram' panel. Leave all the settings default except -- at the bottom of the settings, in the `Queries` section -- select `selected` from the dropdown menu, and then highlight the two separate queries you have created above. This will combine the results from both queries on one panel. This method will simply stack the results of one query on the results of the other query. If you hover over the top stacked query results, you will get the running total for that time segment.